Qutip mesolve gives me non sensible result when I let the state |e><g| decay under the collapse operator sigma - (or destroy(2) in qutip)
I am trying to solve the master equation with H = 0 and c_ops=[destroy(2)] using qutip mesolve. The initial density matrix is |e><g| where |e> is the excited state [basis(2,1)] and |g> is the ground state [basis(2,0)]. The evolution keeps the initial density matrix constant, although my derivation shows that it simply decays with rate 1/2.
Here is the code that I gathered from a Jupiter notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from qutip import *
print(qutip.__version__)
nI = 2; # number of internal states
σm = destroy(2)
σp = create(2)
H = 0 * qeye(2)
c_ops = [σm]
ex = basis(2,1)
rho = ex * ex.dag()* σm.dag()
period = 2*np.pi
tlist = np.linspace(0, 1. * period, 100  + 1)
rho
result = mesolve(H, rho, tlist, c_ops, [σm], options=Options(max_step=1e-4,nsteps=10000))
out = mesolve(H, rho, tlist, c_ops)#, options=Options(nsteps=10000))
out = mesolve(L, rho, tlist)
exp_real = np.real(result.expect[0])
exp_imag = np.imag(result.expect[0])
out.states

The output states are the same as the initial state as a function of time. I feel that this is wrong, and according to my calculations the state should be exp(-0.5t)*rho(0). Can someone help me with that?
